# VB.net Gecko WebBrowser DocumentCompleted not compatible?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, event-handling, geckofx

I'm using GeckoBrowser, as I find it displays and loads pages faster than the native WebBrowser(IE). The only issue I'm having is when to tell the page has finished loading so I can then run more code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    End Sub
    Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Label1.Text = "YES"
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error I get is "Method 'GeckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted' cannot handle event 'DocumentCompleted' because they do not have a compatible signature.

I've tried changing 'WebBrowserDocumentEventArgs' to 'GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs' but that says 'Type - is not defined'.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you hit Ctrl + . when it says undefined, does it prompt you to import the Gecko namespace?

Comment: Don't try to declare the event handler yourself. Use the Properties window in the designer or the drop-downs at the top of the code window to generate the event handler for you, with the correct signature. Get rid of that code you have first.

Comment: THANK YOU @jmcilhinney ! That did the trick. I'm just so used to keyboard mashing and not using the supplied tools. Too much of an oldschool coder *winks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jmcilhinney's solution worked, just used drop downs at the top.
All I really needed was to add Imports Gecko.Events at the top